# How to hide MenuItem in the toolbar in certain situations?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a form screen that is also an information screen, but in different states. When the user enters to create I want to hide the MenuItem that assigns to delete.
How to do this without breaking the app?
I'm trying to call it like this:

```
val menu = findViewById<MenuItem>(R.id.deleteBarra)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#ChangingTheMenu) about it, but you basically want to do your menu setup in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu`. `onPrepareOptionsMenu` gets called every time the menu needs to be displayed (instead of once, during setup).

So you can set a boolean or whatever to say whether the item should be shown, and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to redisplay it. In `prepareOptionsMenu()` you have access to the menu itself, so you can check that boolean and set the visibility on the appropriate item

Answer (score 0):

Under what condition you want it to be hidden, you can add it under that condition.

```
  menu.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

or

```
   menu.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: But I need only one item to be hidden

Comment: take a look at : https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/how+to+hide+menu+items+in+android